# Does my design adhere to 3NF?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I created this schema with OpenOffice.

Does this design adhere to 3NF ?

(A relationship link between **Equipment** and **Supplier_Equipment** , **Customer** and **Membership** should be created but OpenOffice isn't allowing me to do so.)

[image]

Comment: The L:M:N `Hire_Equipement` relation suggests that a Hire can be related to many Customers. If that is your requirement, I see no serious problem with the design.

Comment: @ypercube No, that isn't my intention. How to fix it? by adding customer_id column to 'Hire' table?

Comment: I think the same was suggested in your previous question. Yes: 1.Add `customer_id` to `Hire` 2.Drop the relationships between `Hire_Equipement` and the two tables: `Hire` and `Customer` 3.Make `(customer_id, order_id)` the primary key of `Hire` 4.Recreate the `Hire_Equipement-Hire` relationship targeting the new composite PK. 5.Add a new 1:N relationship between `Customer` and `Hire` (via `customer_id`).

Comment: Alternative: 1.Add `customer_id` to `Hire` 2.Drop only one relationship, between `Hire_Equipement` and `Customer` 3.Change the PK of `Hire_Equipment` to `(equipment_id, order_id)` and drop the `customer_id` from that table 4.Keep the `Hire_Equipement-Hire` relationship as it is. 5.Add a new 1:N relationship between `Customer` and `Hire` (via `customer_id`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this conforms to 3NF as far as I can see.

Basically 3NF is met when all non-key values (assuming natural keys here) in relations are non-transitively functionally dependent on the key.  Surrogate keys don't count for this analysis since category.name is not functionally dependent on category.category_id.  In fact, category.name is probably your natural key and category.category_id is functionally dependent on it for purposes of this analysis (because it is in essence a join dependency stand-in or surrogate for your natural key).  Going through your tables here I do not spot any cases where this is violated.

The one obvious change that this suggests is what was mentioned in the comments by others, to move customer_id into hire and out of hire_equipment (if third party loans of equipment are supported you probably want customer_id in both places though).